# python3 formatting SQL response from rows to string

Tags: python-3.x, printing

im trying to print values from database and im getting this output:

```
[('CPDK0NHYX9JUSZUYASRVFNOMKH',), ('CPDK0KUEQULOAYXHSGUEZQGNFK',), ('CPDK0MOBWIG0T5Z76BUVXU5Y5N',), ('CPDK0FZE3LDHXEJRREMR0QZ0MH',)]
```

but will like to have this fromat:

```
'CPDK0NHYX9JUSZUYASRVFNOMKH'|'CPDK0KUEQULOAYXHSGUEZQGNFK'|'CPDK0MOBWIG0T5Z76BUVXU5Y5N'|'CPDK0FZE3LDHXEJRREMR0QZ0MH'
```

Python3

existing code

```
from coinpayments import CoinPaymentsAPI
from datetime import datetime
from lib.connect import *
import argparse
import json

sql = 'SELECT txn_id FROM coinpayment_transactions WHERE status = 0 '

mycursor.execute(sql)

result = mycursor.fetchall()

mydb.close()

print(result)
```

Comment: You need to show the code you are using to get your current output, at the very least.

Comment: `"|".join(["'{}'".format(x[0]) for x in data]` assuming your data is a list of tuples after you read it from your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are getting is a list of tuples and it is stored in result object. If you want the output to be formatted the way you say then do this

```
#Paste this instead of print(result)
output=''

for i in result:
    if (output!=''):
        output=output+'|'+"'"+i[0]+"'"
    else:
        output=output+"'"+i[0]+"'"
print(output)
```

The better way to do these kinds of thing is using [join](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) and `format()` methods of string.

Comment: getting this error:

output=output+"'"+i[0]+"'"
NameError: name 'output' is not defined

Comment: @ rimalonfire  i have one more problem , can you help on some chat or should i just add here?

Comment: the 'value' im geting from the string what we was talkin before about

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```py
output = '|'.join([f"'{row[0]}'" for row in result])
print(output)
```